# Как подружить остальные сайты с конфигом gitlab'a?

Tags: nginx, gitlab

Установил gitlab на сервер (GitLab CE Omnibus package).

В файле `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` задал домен `http://gitlab.lan/`, все работает нормально.

Но есть же на сервере nginx, та, что не вшита в omnibus. Так вот, в `/etc/nginx/sites-available` у меня есть файл test, в котором прописан конфиг для тестового домена (ну, например, это будет другой сайт):

```
server {
    listen *:80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name test.lan;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-test.log;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

Но по адресу `http://test.lan/` открывается gitlab. Почему так происходит?

Что нужно сделать, чтобы другие сайты тоже жили нормальной жизнью?

p.s. Файл `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   test.lan
127.0.1.1   sanu-VirtualBox

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**UPD**:

Ubuntu стоит на virtualbox, gitlab стоит на этой убунте.
`http://gitlab.lan` я открываю и на пк, на котором установлен virtualbox (он же как пк в локальной сети), также я могу зайти на этот адрес внутри самой ubuntu.

`http://test.lan` - я открываю внутри ubuntu, но этот адрес будет доступен также извне, только по нему должно быть доступно то, что находится в `/usr/share/nginx/html`, а не gitlab - как это сейчас.

`/etc/hosts` - находится на машине с ubuntu, на которой установлен gitlab.

т.е. в сумме, есть пк с виндой и с виртуалкой, внутри виртуалки убунта, на которой установлены gitlab и nginx.

**UPD 2**:

Содержимое всех файлов в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

Файл `default`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;
}
```

Файл `test`:

```
server {
    listen *:80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name test.lan;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-test.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        expires max;
    }
}
```

**UPD 3**

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size            1024m;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server_tokens off;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**UPD 4**

Файл `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf`:

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket;
}

server {
  listen *:80;

  server_name gitlab.lan;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

  client_max_body_size 0;

  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log gitlab_access;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 422 /422.html;
  error_page 500 /500.html;
  error_page 502 /502.html;
  location ~ ^/(404|422|500|502)\.html$ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    internal;
  }

}
```

Comment: на какой машине установлен gitlab? на какой машине установлен nginx? на какой машине вы «открываете» `http://gitlab.lan`? на какой машине вы «открываете» `http://test.lan`? на какой машине находится приведённый вами файл (вероятно, речь про `/etc/hosts`)? укажите, пожалуйста, всю эту информацию прямо в вопросе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, обновил вопрос

Comment: какая программа на сервере слушает 80 порт? `$ sudo lsof -iTCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin,
`nginx   935       root    6u  IPv4   8550      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`
`nginx   971 gitlab-www    6u  IPv4   8550      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`
`nginx   972 gitlab-www    6u  IPv4   8550      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`
`nginx   973 gitlab-www    6u  IPv4   8550      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`
`nginx   974 gitlab-www    6u  IPv4   8550      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)`

Comment: Порт 80 в конечном счёте может слушать только кто-то один. Я тоже некогда с этим воевал, в итоге установил Gitlab через Docker и настроил прозрачный прокси на него. Но это решение, возможно, слишком радикальное для вашего случая.

Comment: @D-side, Может можно как-то заставить gitlab слушать какой-нибудь 9090 порт, а в основном nginx сделать gitlab.lan на 80 порту и направлять его на gitlab.lan:9090 ? Если да, то как?

Comment: @sanu0074 надо копаться в содержимом Omnibus-пакета, чем сломать его самостоятельность и обновляемость :) В целом моё решение основано на том же, просто работает на собственном виртуальном сетевом стеке с собственным адресом, поэтому и коллизии двух 80-ых портов нет.

Comment: @D-side, к сожалению у меня нет столько опыта, я не знаю как это сделать. Вы наверное имеете ввиду поднять отдельную машинку для gitlab'a?

Comment: Эм... и да, и нет. Почитайте, что такое Docker и как он работает, я не возьмусь это объяснить в одном комментарии :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > в `/etc/nginx/sites-available` у меня есть файл test

   чтобы «задействовать» этот файл, надо сделать «мягкую ссылку» (*symlink*) на этот файл в каталоге `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s ../sites-available/test /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```

   и перезагрузить *nginx*:

   ```
   $ sudo service nginx reload
   ```
2. также в конфигурации *nginx* у вас отсутствует директива *root*. точнее, она указана только для одного *location*-а. поместите её непосредственно в секции *server*.
3. и удалите файл (точнее, *symlink*) `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`: благодаря директиве `defalut_server` он «перехватывает» все имена сервера на себя.
4. сопоставляя всю приведённую информацию (в том числе выдачу lsof, где указано, что процесссы nginx, который слушает 80-й порт, работают от имени пользователя *gitlab-www*), можно сделать вывод, что конфигурация в `/etc/nginx` не имеет никакого отношения к той программе *nginx*, которая у вас запущена. исправлять надо ту конфигурацию, которую использует именно запущенная программа. возможно, искать её следует где-нибудь в районе `/etc/gitlab`.
5. раз обнаружилась другая конфигурация, можно добавить в неё ваши «enabled»-файлы. просто добавьте в самом конфе файла `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf` строку, аналогичную строке из `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

   ```
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
   ```

Comment: об этом я знаю, и symlink есть в `sites-enabled`. Я думаю что здесь конфлик с nginx вшитой в gitlab и той что стоит отдельно. Хотя я могу ошибаться

Comment: Да, я сейчас так и сделал, результат не изменился

Comment: Сделал, всего там два файла

Comment: Удалил и перезагрузил nginx, тоже никакой роли не сыграло. В вопрос еще добавил nginx.conf, может это еще как-то поможет разобраться

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, Omnibus-пакет имеет внутри собственный `nginx`, поэтому лезть в системные конфиги решительно бесполезно.

Comment: @sanu0074, судя по содержимому конфигурации, та программа nginx, которая слушает 80-й порт, не имеет к этой конфигурации никакого отношения: в выдаче lsof фигурирует пользователь gitlab-www, который не упоминается в конфигурации. так что разбирайтесь, где и как (с какими параметрами) у вас запускается nginx/

Comment: Насчет п.4, я обновил вопрос, приложил этот конфиг, посмотрите, может что-то удастся придумать

Comment: Теперь работает:) Спасибо! А скажите пожалуйста, сторонний nginx при этом должен быть установлен и работать? Или же его можно снести, а конфиги перенести в `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/`?

Comment: @sanu0074, это совершенно другой вопрос, требующий для полноценного ответа изложения (вами) ещё горы информации.

Comment: Тогда на этом этапе оставлю все как есть) Думаю если конфиги основных сайтов ложить в `/etc/nginx/sites-available` то все будет ок.